# when i compile x264, get error undefined reference to sync_fetch_and_add_4

Tags: c, mingw, x264

i use mingw and msys on windows 7(64 bit) to compile x264.
the following is the error showed:
libx264.a(frame.o):frame.c:(.text+0x2c2d): undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_
and_add_4'
collect2.exe: error：ld reutrn 1
Makefile:182: recipe for target 'x264.exe' failed
make: *** [x264.exe] Error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your mingw/gcc version? __sync_fetch_and_add is built-in gcc's function from version 4.0 afaik. May be it is related to this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28671
Anyway try to update your gcc.